# Is it possible for a single printf() function to execute multiple times while getting input from getchar() in a loop?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, eof, getchar

I was expecting getchar() != EOF to always return a single Boolean value which will be assigned to 'c' and the output will be either 0 or 1 for every iteration of the loop however, i'm getting multiple output for single input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d\n",c = (getchar() != EOF));
    }
}
```

For
input 1, the
output is 11,
and for
input -2, the
output is 111.

What could be causing it to print multiple times?

Comment: Your loop causes it to print multiple times. Further, your program doesn't terminate; it pauses, waiting for you to type more data after the first input. Also, the output should be appearing with each `1` on a line on its own. You should be learning at least C99 (preferably C18), so you should be using `int main(void)` — explicitly stating the return type.  The implicit `int` return type rule was made obsolete by C99, most of 20 years ago.  If your compiler isn't whingeing, it is time to upgrade it — or the options you use. The C standard uses `#include <stdio.h>` with a space; so should you.

Comment: 1 <enter> - 2 <enter>

Answer (score 1):

The extra output is because for each input you have an additional character for the line terminator.

Try this to see exactly what is returned by getchar() for each of your inputs :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while(1)
    {
      c = getchar();
      printf( "x%x\n", c );
      /* printf("%d\n",c = (getchar() != EOF)); */
    }
}
```

When you enter 1, you get two characters,

```
x31
xa
```

When you type -2, you have three characters,

```
x2d
x32
xa
```

Since none of the above are EOF, you get multiple "1"s from your routine.